# Mouse Hower on TextBlock

Tags: wpf, image, c#-4.0, mouseevent, textblock

The idea is when mouse howler above `TextBlock`, new `Image` is appear and it possible to click on it. When mouse leave the `TextBlock` - `Image` should disappear.

Meanwhile I came to this, but still unable to continue:

```
<Style x:Key="HoverHighlightTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,0,3,0"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

`Expected result`

[image]

Comment: You wanna show the image at the `right corner` of the text box when the `mouseover` event fired. And sametime you should be able to `write` in the text box while the image is appearing. And when you leave the text box (mouseleave event fired), the image should be disappeared. **Is this what you need?**

Comment: Exactly beside the fact that it should be TextBlock not TextBox. Textblock act as Label, he not letting to write.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow the below steps.

1. Create a `stackpanel` (orientation is set to horizontal) or any other appropriate control and add `text box` and `image` controls inside it.
2. `Hide` the `borders` of text box and the image controls so that only the stackpanel border is visible.
3. When the `mouseover` event fired, set the image control to be `appeared.`
4. When the `mouseleave` event fired, set the image control to be `disappeared`.

I haven't tested this. But this might help you to get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution based on sa_ddam213 answer:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtblkSelectedItem" Text="My Textblock">
<TextBlock.ToolTip>
  <ToolTip PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtblkSelectedItem}" Placement="Right" HorizontalOffset="-20">
    <Image Source="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1849109.png" Width="10" Height="10"/>
  </ToolTip>
</TextBlock.ToolTip>
```

The idea, is positioning tooltip inside textblock can be achived by using ToolTip

> Placement="Right" HorizontalOffset="-20"

properties

Comment: Great..!! If you click the text block, will the image be still `appeared`?